# Disable Write operation in ReactiveCrudRepository

Tags: spring, spring-webflux

In my case, due to some reason, I need to read data from the tables owned by different reason. In my application, I want to disable write on the table. One solution I think is to inherit `ReactiveCrudRepository` and create an interface which throws exception on write/update operation.

Is there any other clean and maintainable method available for such use-cases?

Comment: how about read-only user?

Comment: This is the first thought I have. But we are sharing common database and other tables are also being used. Creating separate user will incur more db connections. Right now, connections are limited due to the applications running on database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two options here:

---

## First option

Create a read-only user (which has permissions only for reading) in DB and connect to DB from your application with this user.

---

## Second option

If the first option is not suitable in your case, then:

Create a generic repository which has only methods for reading like this: (extend it from `Repository` as it does not contain any method)

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface ReadOnlyReactiveRepository<T, ID> extends Repository<T, ID> {

    Flux<T> findAll();

    Mono<T> findById(ID id);
   
    ... any methods you want
}
```

**Note:** Dont forget to annotate this generic repository with `@NoRepositoryBean` which is used to avoid creating repository proxies for interfaces that actually match the criteria of a repo interface but are not intended to be one.

And extend your domain repository from that repository, not from `ReactiveCrudRepository` like this:

```
public interface YourDomainRepository extends ReadOnlyReactiveRepository<YourDomain, String> {
    
}
```

Comment: Thanks @kerbermeister for the answer. Just want to know that will it generate SQL for method like findByNamesIn and so on? I guess yes as it is inheriting Repository anyway.

Comment: Of course it will

Comment: and of course, you should put those methods in YourDomainRepository as they may be specific for the actual domains